# Using more than one linker in the same make

Tags: llvm, gentoo, gold-linker

I'm currently trying to do a source installation of LLVM in a gentoo i686 virtual machine, and in the process of compiling (make) the default linker (bfd) throws an error because of a shortage in memory.

In this site I found that changing the linker to gold fixes this issue (as increasing the virtual machine's memory or creating a swap file is not currently an option), and it did, but when linking another library it threw another error that the original linker did not.

My question is, could there be an issue in using different linkers for differents parts of the make process?

Thanks in advance